# Pandas series bar chart plotting

Tags: pandas

I have the following data in the format of pandas.core.series.Series (after processing the original DataFrame), and I want to do some visualisation of the data. What I need is to plot a bar chart per Fruit (Apple, Pear, Oranges, etc.)  where the annual production of producers X1, X2, X3 are next to each other on the chart (multiple bar chart). The x axis of the figure should be the Year. 
Could anyone help please!
Thanks

The data:

```
Fruit        Producer        Year    Production (tons)
Apple        X1              1981    125
                             1982    146
                             1983    251
                             1984    278
                             1985    161
             X2              1981    510
                             1982    456
                             1983    531
                             1984    563
                             1985    508
             X3              1981     68
                             1982    121
                             1983    126
                             1984    189
                             1985    134
Pear         X1              1981    126
                             1982    148
                             1983    255
                             1984    272
                             1985    166
             X2              1981    515
                             1982    454
                             1983    539
                             1984    565
                             1985    558
             X3              1981    516
                             1982    485
                             1983    567
                             1984    519
                             1985    588
Oranges      X1              1981     68
                             1982    100
                             1983    109
                             1984    190
                             1985    136                      
             X2              1981     50
                             1982    155
                             1983    126
                             1984    155
                             1985    139     
             X3              1981     12
                             1982    163
                             1983    198
                             1984    174
                             1985    136
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. We will gladly help you if you are stuck at some point.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/